# On the relation between categorification and chromatic redshift

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy, chromatic-homotopy

In the introduction to the paper *Higher traces, noncommutative motives, and the categorified Chern character*, Hoyois, Scherotzke and Sibilla write the following.

> An important insight emerging from topology is that climbing up the chromatic ladder is related to studying invariants of spaces that are higher-categorical in nature.

The only example that I am aware of is the theory of categorified vector bundles, and its relation with chromatic-level-$2$ cohomology theories, including elliptic cohomology, and the algebraic K-theory spectrum of complex K-theory. See for instance [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/BDR+2-vector+bundle) nLab page and the references therein.

**Question.** Are there other examples of this phenomenon, and is there a conceptual reason why categorification should be related to chromatic redshifting?

Answer (score 6):

The paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5699 by Torlief Veen involves arbitrarily large chromatic redshifts via higher topological Hochschild homology.  I know of no other examples like that.